# Google Structured Testing Tool is not showing image from my domain

Tags: image, schema.org, google-rich-snippets

When I click on "Preview", the Google Structured Testing Tool don't show the image from my domain. But it shows the image of any other link, from [Google images](https://www.google.com/search?q=image&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjfk8701v3dAhWBD5AKHbwUAe4Q_AUIDigB&biw=1366&bih=695). Why?

```html
<main itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/NewsArticle">
    <meta itemprop="mainEntityOfPage" content="https://isMyDomain.net/?p=one-page">
    <span itemprop="author publisher" itemscope itemtype="https://pending.schema.org/NewsMediaOrganization">
        <meta itemprop="url" content="https://isMyDomain.net">
        <meta itemprop="name" content="siteName">
        <link itemprop="sameAs" href="https://www.facebook.com/mypage" />
        <link itemprop="sameAs" href="https://twitter.com/mypage" />
        <link itemprop="sameAs" href="https://www.instagram.com/mypage" />
        <span itemprop="logo" itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/ImageObject">
            <meta itemprop="url" content="https://isMyDomain.net/img/myLogo.png">
            <meta itemprop="width" content="488">
            <meta itemprop="height" content="60">
        </span>
    </span>

    <span itemprop="image" itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/ImageObject">
    <meta itemprop="url" content="https://isMyDomain.net/img/posts/d40N.jpg">
    <meta itemprop="width" content="634">
    <meta itemprop="height" content="342">            
    </span>

    <article>
        <header>                    
        <h1 itemprop="headline">Title</h1>  
        <time itemprop="datePublished" datetime="2018-10-11T09:45:00-03:00">
        11/10/2018 09h45</time>
        <meta itemprop="dateModified" content="2018-10-11T09:45:00-03:00"> 
        </header>

        <div itemprop="articleBody">
            <p>article body</p> 
        </div>
    </article>
</main>
```

You can see the preview button when testing [a link from BBC news articles](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-europe-45822845).

Comment: 1) The snippet you posted doesn’t give a "Preview" button in SDTT. Can you include a working minimal example? 2) You said that it shows the image with the links from the linked Google Image Search. I tried a few links but didn’t get to see the preview button (not even any detected structure). Can you link to a working example?

Comment: @unor You only can see the "Preview" button if you have a AMP page (atleast for me). But anyways i updaded my question with the full structured data. Why is not it showing the images from my domain? Maybe it's because my domain is new? I created my domain 5 days ago.

Comment: Do you have a link to someone’s AMP page that shows the 'Preview' button? Even [Google’s own code examples](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/article) don’t show this button.

Comment: @unor Yes, you can see the preview with a link from bbc news [articles](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-europe-45822845). I think that the preview on Google Testing Tool is not working propely, because now it's showing my image on the card, and it's showing the images from bbc news (only shows the logo). But there's still something missing, my logo is not showing on the preview, the size of my logo is 488x60, is it right? And i put it on `itemprop="author publisher"`, as you can see on the code from my question.

Comment: Notes about your markup (not necessarily related to your issue): 1) Don’t specify `https://pending.schema.org/`, always specify `https://schema.org/` (or `http`), even for terms from Pending. 2) If a `meta` element has a URL as value, you must use `link` instead of `meta`.

Comment: @unor Alright, thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Getting the 'Preview' button

It seems that the 'Preview' button appears if you include a `link` element that points to an actual AMP page (it doesn’t seem to work with a fake/example URL), e.g.:

```html
<link rel="amphtml" href="https://www.bbc.com/news/amp/world-europe-4582284">
```

In the preview, the snippets will be linked to this AMP URL.

#### Displaying images in the preview

The preview tool only displays images if they are already indexed by Google Search. If they are not yet indexed, a placeholder image will be displayed. See [The Google Search Preview Tool](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6398748):

> #### Rich card placeholder images and title
>
> If you are testing rich card markup, you can see your actual image in the preview if we confirm, or verify, that the image URL is in our index.  However, the preview displays a placeholder image if our systems cannot verify the image URL. Even so, when your rich card markup reaches our systems, the image you provide should be shown correctly in the actual Google Search results.